# upload files to wowza from android

Tags: stream, wowza

I have installed wowza server and able to play files from client side using video view in android now i have to record video and have to upload files to wowza server. how to write server side app? and how to connect that from android code? does any one have any experience in that?.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Wowza built in to do this.  You could use scp and an app like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perdeas.droidscp&hl=en to get the files up there.  Another idea would be to build a web interface to upload the files, then have that application scp to your Wowza server.  Still another option is to get the files to s3, and stream from there if your files are hosted on ec2.