# How to upload file to wowza media server via android device?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, live-streaming, android-video-player

Hi i want to upload video file into wowza media server. I configured wowza server in my system. I uploaded video file into webserver.What is the procedure for uploading file into wowza? Can anybody tell me how can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you want to do? You mention that you have upload a video file to your webserver. Do you want to know how one can similarly upload a file into your wowza server?... Are you trying to do this on an Android device?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to access the media from a client,
upload/store your media files into on the wowza-server at the following path:

```
[wowza-server-installation-path]/content
```

More info is available [**here**](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217#contentStorage).

AFAIK uploading to wowza server from a client is not provided in the default packages. You might also want to take a look at [stackoverflow.com/questions/10738387/upload-files-to-wowza-from-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738387/upload-files-to-wowza-from-android)